# Classifying sentences with overlapping words

Tags: python, twitter, nltk, document-classification

I've this CSV file which has comments (tweets,  comments). I want to classify them into 4 categories, viz.

- Pre Sales
- Post Sales
- Purchased
- Service query

Now the problems that I'm facing are these :

1. There is a huge number of overlapping words between each of the
   categories, hence using NaiveBayes is failing.
2. The size of tweets being only 160 chars, what is the best way to
   prevent words from one category falling into the another.
3. What all ways should I select the features which can take care of both the 160 char tweets and a bit lengthier facebook comments.
4. Please let me know of any reference link/tutorial link to follow up the same, being a newbee in this field

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  You might want to look at http://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html combined with Porter's stemming alorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be so quick to write off Naive Bayes. It does fine in many domains where there are lots of weak clues (as in "overlapping words"), but no absolutes. It all depends on the features you pass it. I'm guessing you are blindly passing it the usual "bag of words" features, perhaps after filtering for stopwords. Well, if that's not working, try a little harder.

A good approach is to read a couple of hundred tweets and see how *you* know which category you are looking at. That'll tell you what kind of things you need to distill into features. But be sure to look at lots of data, and focus on the general patterns.

An example (but note that I *haven't* looked at your corpus): Time expressions may be good clues on whether you are pre- or post-sale, but they take some work to detect. Create some features "past expression", "future expression", etc. (*in addition* to bag-of-words features), and see if that helps. Of course you'll need to figure out how to detect them first, but you don't have to be perfect: You're after anything that can help the classifier make a better guess. "Past tense" would probably be a good feature to try, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a complex problem.

1. How do you define the categories? Get as many tweets and FB posts as you can and tag them all with the correct categories to get some ground truth data
2. Then you can identify which words/phrases are the best for identifying particular category using e.g. [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

Look into [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) they have tutorials for text processing and classification.

Comment: Mirsoval the problem is that consider classification into-"Pre Sales" & "Post Sales". Now I observed that both these classes differ by words such as "will purchase" & "purchased it"/"already purchased".

Comment: My point is that you should not so it by observation. Observation can give you ideas on what you should start with, but ultimately you want to make decisions and write your classifiers based on solid data. You need to go out and get sufficient data first. Then get some sort of hard numbers like "the phrase 'will purchase' appears in 80% of tweets which I think are in category 'Pre Sales'" Make your decisions on this data

Comment: Can you also please help me with any tutorial/link which kind of solves similar problem/on similar lines,  as Im also facing a similar issue

Comment: The scikit-learn link in the answer is exactly the tutorial you're looking for.

Comment: @mirosval at which step do I need to use PCA. Secondly, how does one even use PCA in text data ?

Comment: This is a discussion that is too complex for comments on a SO answer. Start by getting a database of tweets/text which are tagged by the right category, then post questions on PCA specifics.